# Notation or formula for matrix traversal?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, notation, path-connected

This question: [Password 'spatial' pattern?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/160594/89737) gave me ideas about the properties of *"walks"* (continuous or relative, **ordered** paths) of *keyboards* (matrices), and now I am curious if there is a way to express such properties / relations on matrices using formal mathematical symbols.

Your (QWERTY) keyboard is kind of like a matrix $M$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{Q} & \mathbf{W} & \mathbf{E} & \mathbf{R} & \mathbf{T} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{U} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{O} & \mathbf{P} & \\
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{D} & \mathbf{F} & \mathbf{G} & \mathbf{H} & \mathbf{J} & \mathbf{K} & \mathbf{L} & \mathbf{\cdot} \\
\mathbf{\cdot} & \mathbf{Z} & \mathbf{X} & \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{V} & \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{N} & \mathbf{M} & \mathbf{\cdot} & \mathbf{\cdot} \end{bmatrix}$$

To better illustrate my question, let me introduce the three basic kinds of *walks*<sup>[1](https://github.com/catb0t/keyboardwalk/tree/master/keyboardwalk.py#L290)</sup> over a matrix like this, since that is my use-case:

- **Linear**: $\{\ \mathbf{A\ A\ S\ D}\ \}$, $\{\ \mathbf{E\ R\ F\ G}\ \}$ and $\{\ \mathbf{K\ U\ Y\ H\ J\ K}\ \}$ are all *linear walks* on this matrix, in that if you follow each set through the matrix, the following is always true of any two successive elements $A$ and $B$: 
  $$\lvert\ (A_x, A_y)  - (B_x, B_y)\ \rvert\leq (1, 1)\ $$

  That is, their coordinate pairs $(x, y)$ never differ by more than $(1, 1)$.

  A simple, recursive, contextless algorithm to determine whether a given set $S$ is a *linear walk* of a matrix $M$ can be written:

  1. If the  difference between the coordinates of $S_{1+n}$ and $S_{2+n}$ is in $\{\ (0, 0),\ …\ (1, 1) \ \}$, repeat this step, letting $n$ be the number of previous steps.
  2. Otherwise, only the part of $S$ traversed thus far is a *linear walk* on $M$, which may be $\emptyset$.
- **Simple** or **trivial nonlinear**: $\{\ \mathbf{F\ G\ H\ D}\ \}$, $\{\ \mathbf{A\ S\ D\ Q}\ \}$, $\{\ \mathbf{T\ G\ H\ R}\ \}$, and $\{\ \mathbf{Z\ X\ C\ V\ B\ S}\ \}$ are all *simple nonlinear walks* on this matrix, in that a single-lookaround, one-directional iterative algorithm on each of three or fewer states of $S$ (unsorted, sorted by $x$ then $y$, and $y$ then $x$) can show all elements have coordinates within $\{\ (0, 0),\ …\ (1, 1) \ \}$ of at least one other element, such as:

  1. Let $C$ be the coordinate pairs of each $S_n$, in the same order as $S$.
  2. Let $X$ be the ordering of $C$ by $C_{n_x}$, and $Y$ the ordering of $C$ by $C_{n_y}$.
  3. Accumulate three sets $V_n$ of the differences of successive pairs in each of $C$, $X$, $Y$.
  4. If any of $V_n$ has all its elements within $\{\ (0, 0),\ …\ (1, 1) \ \}$, $S$ is a *simple nonlinear walk* on $M$.
  5. Otherwise, $S$ may be a *complex nonlinear walk* on $M$.
- **Complex nonlinear**: $\{\ \mathbf{A\ S\ D\ E\ Z}\ \}$, $\{\ \mathbf{A\ S\ D\ Q\ W\ E\ Z\ X\ C}\ \}$, and $\{\ \mathbf{R\ T\ Y\ D\ F\ G\ X\ C\ V}\ \}$ are all *complex nonlinear walks* on $M$ in that

  - all elements have coordinates within $\{\ (0, 0),\ …\ (1, 1) \ \}$ of at least one other element, and
  - a single-lookaround, one-directional iterative algorithm would need to be performed on **every possible permutation** of $S$ in order to tell if $S$ is a *simple nonlinear walk* on $M$,
  - **and** [you only need $len(S)*{len(S) - 1}$ calculations](https://github.com/catb0t/keyboardwalk/blob/master/keyboardwalk.py#L209) to determine whether $S$ is a *complex nonlinear walk* on $M$.

(Note well, that all *linear* and *simply nonlinear walks* are in the set of *complex nonlinear walks*, but not the inverse.)

**Is there another or better way to express these kinds of subsets, paths, or algorithms on a given "keyboard" matrix, perhaps using set notation?**

<sub>(1): That I have determined to be disparate after spending 3 days programming and experimenting about this.</sub>

Comment: What can be improved, please let me know

Comment: Treat the keyboard as a [grid graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph) with diagonal edges and self-edges added, then a linear walk is just a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)). I haven't thought about your other kinds of walks.

Comment: I don't quite understand these definitions.  I would look into the graph theory literature on the difference between walks, paths, Eulerian paths, etc.  (I didn't downvote though.)